# KeyError: ‘__builtins__’ in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, keyerror

I am new to numpy and use a lab instrument that returns data as a numpy array, which I am in turn storing as part of a list with the structure

```
raw_data = [[int, numpy.ndarray, int, int]]
```

I want to grab the biggest number from the second column of that numpy array (many rows and 2 columns), so I wrote this code:

```
…code that collects data and writes it to the raw_data list…
max_ccounts = raw_data[1][1].max(axis=0)[1]
print(max_ccounts)
```

But I constantly get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/kimfook-lee/Desktop/automated_TPI.py", line 75, in <module>
    max_ccounts = raw_data[1][1].max(axis=0)[1]
    KeyError: '__builtins__'
```

I know that `raw_data[1][1]` points to a numpy array because I printed it. I wasn’t sure if I was accessing the list elements properly so I tried to do it on my own in the terminal, using the exact same numpy array that was printed:

```
>>> raw_data1 = np.array([[7200, 876],[8000,840271]])
>>> raw_data = [[0,raw_data1,10,10]]
>>> max_ccounts = raw_data[0][1].max(axis=0)[1]
>>> print(max_ccounts)
840271
```

Whenever I search for KeyError, I only find things related to dictionaries, and can’t find any information related to **builtins** or numpy. What is causing this error and how can it be resolved?

**EDIT:**

Following the advice of ForceBru I went ahead and added some temp variables and printed them to find the error.

```
…code that collects data and writes it to the raw_data list…
tmp1 = raw_data[1]
print('tmp1:', tmp1)
tmp2 = tmp1[1]
print('tmp2', tmp2)
tmp3=tmp2.max(axis=0)
print('tmp3', tmp3)
tmp4 = tmp3[1]
print('tmp4', tmp4)
```

Now there is the same error with a different traceback.

```
KeyError: '__builtins__'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/kimfook-lee/Desktop/automated_TPI.py", line 75, in <module>
    print('tmp1:', tmp1)
RuntimeError: Unable to configure default ndarray.__repr__
```

Comment: "I know that raw_data[1][1] points to a numpy array because I printed it." Okay, so what happens when you try using the rest of the code, `.max(axis=0)[1]`, on that Numpy array? What happens when you try just the `.max(axis=0)` part? Can you reproduce the error using a new Numpy array created from scratch? Can you reproduce the error in other ways? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: You can split that long expression into subexpressions to see which one errors out. `tmp1 = raw_data[1]; tmp2 = tmp1[1]; tmp3 = tmp2.max(axis=0); max_ccounts =tmp3[1]` - do this, but put each statement _on a new line_ and see which line produces the error. I think the very latest version of Python (3.10 maybe) can automatically point out the exact subexpression that caused the error. Then investigate the contents of the corresponding variable (`tmp1` through `tmp3`)

Comment: "Whenever I search for KeyError, I only find things related to dictionaries, and can’t find any information related to builtins or numpy." Did you try explicitly including `__builtins__` and/or `numpy` in your search terms?

Comment: "using the exact same numpy array that was printed:" What happens if you try to compare that array with the one that you got from `raw_data[1][1]`, using `==`?

Comment: How, exactly, are you running this code? This seems to be an error arising from however this code is being executed dynamically

Comment: Also, did you print `raw_data[1][1]` *at the point in the code where the error occurs*? Did you verify its *type*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, yes, i searched with those terms and I verified the type and data of raw_data[1][1] at the point where the error occurs. I have updated my question with the recommendation of ForceBru.

Comment: What specific steps do you take in order to run the program?

Comment: Also, the code is running in the linux terminal as python3 -m automated_TPI (the file name), @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I’ve also checked and I have no problem printing a numpy array using print(array) in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: You should just be using `python3 automated_TPI.py`.  The `-m` method is gives a slightly different environment.

Comment: @TimRoberts even when ommitting the -m I still get the error.

Comment: first you talk about max_ccounts = raw_data[1][1].max(axis=0)[1] then you use max_ccounts = raw_data[1][1].max(axis=0)[1]  which of the two are you actually using ?

Comment: Those look identical to me @pippo1980. I don’t see the difference?

EDIT: I looked up in the code and I see the problem. I am not sure why either would make a difference, although I am actually using raw_data[1][1]

Answer (score 0):

cant figure out the question , but to me

```
import numpy as np

raw_data1 = np.array([[7200, 876],[8000,840271]])
raw_data = [[0,raw_data1,10,10]]
max_ccounts = raw_data[0][1].max(axis=0)[1]

print(max_ccounts)
```

output

```
840271
```